# "the man with the boring, repetitive job who needs more money"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, reading

> You can argue that it is the man with the boring, repetitive job who needs more money to make up for the soul-destroying monotomy of his work.

My teacher said this sentence implied that **the man should receive more money as a compensation for the drudgery of his work**, but I thought **he had no interest in his work but the money he could gain**.

Is my teacher right?

Comment: answer me please.

Comment: Have some patience.

Comment: One can argue what they want. Just as you can argue that all he cares about is the money. Your teacher is simply saying that boring, repetitive jobs, ones that are so monotonous that people lose their spark and die inside, should be compensated higher because of the effects placed onto them by the job. She is right that someone CAN argue that. Doesn't make it true.

Comment: so what about my opinion? \

Comment: You CAN argue your opinion but I, personally, would say hers is more plausible. It all depends on whether the job itself is boring or if the employee is just bored with the job. I think it's easier to take her opinion from it than yours, honestly.

Comment: The sentence quoted says that *someone can argue* what your teacher said: that it is (especially) the person whose job is boring who should be better compensated. What's your question exactly? Did your teacher say that such jobs should be better compensated or just that the sentence says that one could argue that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English language.

Comment: It would help for you to [edit] your question to say what you consider to be the essential difference between your teacher's view and your own. Is it simply a matter of degree (teacher: some interest in his work; yours: no interest in his work)? Is it what 'he' thought he was being paid for (teacher: the drudgery; yours: the work itself)? Is it something else altogether?

Comment: Your interpretation would probably be appropriate if the sentence said ***wants** more money* rather than *needs more money*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked only if your teacher was reading the sentence for what it implies, not what is the better argument for boring work and better pay. Your teacher is correctly reading the sentence as written, that monotony deserves extra compensation.

Your argument is different, although valid, from what the sentence says. Your interpretation especially comes to life in the way the question title takes a portion out of context: It is "the man with the boring, repetitive job who needs more money" or he would not be doing such awful work.